# Unwanted oscillations in Synthetic seismogram

Tags: numerical-modelling, seismic

I have generated a synthetic seismogram using FDTD elastic velocity-stress formulation on a staggered grid. I can't understand origin of oscillations modulating on seismogram. 
[image]

Is it a result of dispersion? 
I have satisfied the grid dispersion criteria (10 grid per minimum wavelength) which keeps it below 5% but still it is very prominent.

Model description:
Velocities: Vp = 2000 m/s;  Vs = 1500 m/s;
Source:  Ricker (20Hz).
Grid spacing:  dx = dv = 1m;
time sampling: dt = 0.1msec

**Edit 1**

I have corrected one problem related to source (now I am using soft source) and it made initial pulse smooth. However its tail still have oscillations.
[image: Pressure corrected]

Comment: 0.1 ms seems like a very short interval, given the other parameters. Does it help at all if you use 1 ms? Make sure you are handling units properly (I find it best to do everything in seconds).

Comment: @kwinkunks I took care of units in first run itself. I carried out experiment with various values of 'dt' but all these oscillations increase with increase in time. I am using a Ricker wavelet of 30Hz frequency. Any suggestions about origin or cause of these oscillations.

Comment: Do you have any sharp edges that introduce oscillations after transformation?

Comment: @WayoftheGeophysicist I have taken a homogeneous model so it doesn't have any discontinuity. Additionally, all the edges have absorbing boundary layers so they won't be producing any reflections.

Comment: Have you considered taking a FFT of your data and identifying the wavelengths corresponding to the oscillation?

Comment: I am really hoping that someone with knowledge of numerical modeling will help with this question. I am very curious to see the answer. My guess would be numerical dispersion but there may be other things to consider. The fact that you used a staggered grid should help reduce this. Is there a relationship between the geometry of the grid and the expected frequencies of the dispersion artifacts? This is a very interesting question and I hope you get a good answer soon.